# Create jQuery plugins including keyup function

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function filtering labels like this:

```
$.filtrele = function(e) {
    var value = $(e).val().toLowerCase();
    var li = $("#dgg > label");
    li.hide();
    li.filter(function() {return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;}).show();
}
```

I use it like this:

```
$('#filt').keyup(function() {
    $.filtrele(this);
});
```

I want to combine these and use like this: `$('#filt').filtrele();` I tried some combinations like this:

```
$.fn.filtrele= function(){
    $(this).keyup(function()
    {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var li = $("#dgg > label");
        li.hide();
        li.filter(function() {return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;}).show();
    });
};
```

But I did not manage it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `$(this).keyup(function()` to `this.keyup(function()` per https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

```
$.fn.filtrele= function(){
    this.keyup(function()
    {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var li = $("#dgg > label");
        li.hide();
        li.filter(function() {return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;}).show();
    });
};
```

Comment: I think in your answer you have mentioned  `$(this).keyup(function()` but according to your answer it should be `this.keyup(function()`. Correct me if am wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks for both true answers.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call like this [**`this.keyup`** not  `$(this).keyup`](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#basic-plugin-authoring), *"This is because our filtrele function is a part of the same object as .keyup()."*

```js
$.fn.filtrele= function(){
    this.keyup(function()
    {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        alert(value);
        var li = $("#dgg > label");
        li.hide();
        li.filter(function() {return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;}).show();
    });
};

$('#filt').filtrele();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="filt" />
```

Comment: Thanks for both true answers.